# Internal Server Error on a PHP app that is calling a function that calls MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Basically I am building a MVC app. In the Model, dbFunctions.php is this code:

```
<?php
require("config.php");
require("dbconnection.php");

class dbFunctions
{
    // setting up the object to connect to the Database
    function __construct() 
    {
        $dbConnect = new dbConnection(); 
    }

    public function insertPortfolioAdminData($value='')
    {
        # code...
    }

    public function login($value='')
    {
        # code...
    }

    public function logout($value='')
    {
        # code...
    }

    public function dbStoreContactForm($value='')
    {
        # code...
    }

    // returns a query with a collection of database objects for the portfolio
    public function fetchAllPortfolioItems()
    {
        $fetchAllPortfolioItemsReturnQry = mysql_query("SELECT description FROM PortfolioItems")  or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ()); 

        if($fetchAllPortfolioItemsReturnQry){
            return $fetchAllPortfolioItemsReturnQry; 
        }
    }

    public function fetchSinglePortfolioItems($primaryKey='')
    {
        # code...
    }

}
?>
```

dbConnection.php

```
<?php 

require("config.php"); 

class dbConnection {

    private $databaseConnection;    

    public function dbConnection(){
        $databaseConnection = mysql_connect(dbHostName,dbUserName,dbPassword) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db(dbDatabaseName) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    public function closeConnection(){
        mysql_close($databaseConnection);
    }

}

?>
```

The controller:

```
<?php 
// Calling the class to do the work on database 
require("./model/dbfunctions.php"); 

$dbMethods = new dbFunctions(); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($dbMethods->fetchAllPortfolioItems()))
{
    $pageContent = $row["description"];
}

// calling the template
require("./views/page_12.php"); 

?>
```

Here's the error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal
>   error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server
>   administrator,
>   webmaster@mvcportfolio.adambourg.com
>   and inform them of the time the error
>   occurred, and anything you might have
>   done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may
>   be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error
>   was encountered while trying to use an
>   ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Basically I am trying to do all my DB work in the model then through the model pass it to the view to output it.

Comment: Check your error log for the actual error and post that.  Then, we can assist you.

Comment: Somewhere on your server (check /var/log on a Linux box) there is an error log.  You need to find that log.  At the end of the log file there will be an error (or many errors).   Edit your original question with the error, and we can help you.  "Internal Server Error" is completely generic and useless for figuring out a problem.

Comment: $fetchAllPortfolioItemsReturnQry ... thatsOneHellOfACamelCasedVariable yikes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's maybe because you're never actually connecting to the database before you query it.

Essentially, you've made a function with the same name as the class for `dbConnection` instead of using the `__construct` method.

Comment: While there could be a problem with his "config.php", there's nothing wrong with a function with the same name as the class. That's how it used to work in PHP4 and PHP5 is backwards compatible as [stated here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) (right below the first example).

Comment: hi jerluc, i'm also getting this same error. but in my case i checked out that i've included connection file before insert query. and in localhost it's working fine. but when i moved project on server then only i'm getting this error. can u tell me please what is next possibility for this error??

Answer (score 4):

I see a few problems that **may** contribute to the error:

1 - You're using `require` for the "config.php" but you should really be using `require_once`. There's no need to load it more than once.

```
// Replace the require('config.php') with:
require_once('config.php');
```

2 - Are you defining constants in your "config.php"? The `dbConnection::dbConnection()` function is looking for constants named `dbHostName`, `dbUserName`, `dbPassword`, and `dbDatabaseName`. Make sure your "config.php" is defining constants.

3 - The `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($dbMethods->fetchAllPortfolioItems()))` in `dbFunctions.php` is wrong. The `mysql_fetch_array` portion of the `while` is "recalculated" on every iteration which means that it's executed over and over again. If you assign the value of `$dbMethods->fetchAllPortfolioItems()` to a variable first, the function is only executed once and the `while` will iterate through the results. Use this instead:

```
$result = $dbMethods->fetchAllPortfolioItems();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $pageContent = $row["description"];
}
```

As per the [`while`](http://ca.php.net/while) documentation:

> It tells PHP to execute the nested
>   statement(s) repeatedly, as long as
>   the while expression evaluates to
>   TRUE.

The `mysql_fetch_array($dbMethods->fetchAllPortfolioItems())` part of the `while` you're using will always evaluate to `TRUE` as long as the query return a row as it's getting called over and over (thus returning the same first row every single time).

The error that's causing the "Internal Server Error" is probably because your script is taking more than the `max_execution_time` allowed in `php.ini`.

Comment: @Snow_Mac - Did any of the thoughts above help you solve the problem? If it's not resolved let me know and I'll see what else I can come up with for you.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. These all fixed it! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

You will see a very clear error message in your server error log, in apache on linux:
/var/log/apache/error.log
and I would also take a look (if it is not clear from the previews log) at the mysql error log, which is also somewhere under /var/log/...